# How to fetch data in nuxt js with amp

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build an amp website with some features, so I need to get some data from API, I have tried many ways but none of them work for me. one of my shote.

```
created () {
    fetch('http://myapi/api/post/', { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }).then(data => {
        this.posts.push('I hope it works');
    });
}
```

I tried many ways but I didn't find the solution yet.

Comment: http://myapi/api/post/ is this url correct?

Comment: yes just I write myapi to make it short

Comment: console.log(data) to see what is the response

Comment: I'm using nuxt js with amp there are no scripts after building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanna utilize Server Side Rendering.

If you want your component data to be avaliable at start from the API you have to use the asyncData Method. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/

```
export default {
  asyncData () {
    return fetch(`https://my-api/api/post/`)
      .then((res) => {
        return { posts: res.data.posts }
      })
  }
}
```

After that you can use the `posts` property like you would have declared it inside your `data()`

Comment: didn't work also here is an example of nuxt js with amp https://github.com/Noah-Lc/nextjs-with-amp/blob/master/plugins/ampify.js

Answer (score 0):

Using the fetch hook:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/

How the fetch hook works:
https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/

```
data() {
  return {
    posts: []
  }
},
async fetch() {
  const response = await this.$http.$get(
    'http://myapi/api/post/',
  )
  this.posts = response
},
```